# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API implementing a demo reset that isn't in Production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022

There is one application with two implementations:  Production and Demo.  The Demo site gets its DB reset on scheduled bases.  This resetting of the DB would kill our customer data in Production.

There are two differences between the two implementations:

1. There are a number of external systems which the demo does not call
2. There is one endpoint the demo has which is called to do the DB reset

At the moment this is all handled by a different source code branch.  There is a special Demo branch that has the special "reset" endpoint.  The external systems are stubbed out by simply commenting out the 6 places in the code.

There has to be a better way.  As far as stubbing out the code correctly, that is easy:  implement dependency injections correctly.  But what about that extra endpoint?  Under no circumstance can that code EVER live in Production.  We simply do not want that source code in any form or fashion to live in the main code, but what is the quickest and easiest way to extra it?

My first thought is to create a new VS2022 project for the demo site.  It would have the Production project as a dependency.  The Demo project would have the Reset endpoint and the stubbed-out services for the extern systems.  Then the Demo project would have its own Program.cs and Startup.  The Demo version of Startup would call the Production Startup and afterward it would make sure the stubbed services were implemented rather than the Production services.

Will this work?  Is there a better way?  Any pitfalls out there to contend with in this approach?

Comment: Use a preprocessor directive.  The code will never get compiled so it cannot be executed.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives.  You can set the options in your compiler instructions so you do not need to comment out code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jwdeng mentioned, you can use [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) to make sure the reset code only ever lives in the demo version.

I'm using directives for the same purpose in my app. The demo version seeds test data data and registers demo services, whereas the production version doesn't seed any data and registers production services.

Here's how that can be done, using a minimal API as an example:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

#if DEMO
app.MapGet("/reset", () =>
{
    // TODO clear database
});
#endif

app.Run();
```

The following minimal API will **only expose the `/reset` endpoint when compiled with the constant `DEMO`**.

To do that, build the app with the `/p:DefineConstants="DEMO"` argument, like so:

```
dotnet build -c Release /p:DefineConstants="DEMO"
```

On the other hand, building it without the `/p:DefineConstants="DEMO"` argument will ensure the `/reset` endpoint will be ignored during compilation.

```
dotnet build -c Release
```